# Создание Main хендлера в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть три хендлера, каждый отвечает за обработку конкретной команды.
Я хочу немного упростить работу для пользователя.

К примеру, юзер шлет запрос в бот, main хендлер его ловит и выдает юзеру инлайн клавиатуру с тремя кнопками. И при нажатии на какую-либо кнопку на клавиатуре, отправлялся запрос в конкретный хендлер для обработки. То есть, нужно в callbackdata передать объект message (именно объект, не его текст, чтобы могли следующие хендлеры с ним работать).

Но он может не влезть из-за ограничения.
Натолкните на мысль, можно ли решить такой вопрос без создания велосипеда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть способ получить текущее сообщение в любом месте кода.

```
from aiogram import types

types.Message.get_current()
```

Ну и как аналоги

```
types.CallbackQuery.get_current()
types.User.get_current()
types.Chat.get_current()
Dispatcher.get_current()
Bot.get_current()
```

О а еще можно просто сохранить в стейт и потом вызвать его.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["whatever_data"] = message.text
    await f()


async def f():
    cur_state = dp.current_state()
    async with cur_state.proxy() as data:
        print(data)
```

Comment: Супер, взял в работу стейт и всё вышло! :)
Благодарствую

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую познакомиться с фабрикой калбека
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

создаем фабрику vote

callback = CallbackData('vote', 'action', 'amount')

создаем калбек на фабрике vote

callback =callback.new(action=f'main', amount=f'open')

создаем клавиатуру

markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

указываем в калбек дату наш сгенерированный калбек

markup.add(types.InliteKeyboardButton(text='text', callback_data=callback))

отправляем сообщение
await message.answer(text, reply_markup=markup)

сразу покажу как его словить

@dp.callback_query_handler(callback .filter(action='vote'))
def ....
Плохо могу передать мыслю читай по коду

Comment: Callback имеет ограничение в 64 байта, объект мессадж не влезет в него
+ вылазит ошибка, из-за того что в калбек отправляю якобы словарь (объект мессадж)